# App doesn't compile in Unity after adding Admob plugin

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

App does not compile in Unity after adding the Admob plugin.
My app was compiling normally, I had already done a couple of tests. Add the AdMob plugin and now instead of compiling, it stays in "Building Player (busy at)" and for more than an hour, nothing happens.
I tried absolutely everything, the Unity version is 2022.1.23f and I have the most up-to-date version of AdMob.

I already tried different solutions on this platform and nothing could help me. It's weird because I have other projects on the same version of Unity and AdMob that compile perfectly.

I tried to create another project and replicate it, update unity and admob, nothing helped.